# SSDT publish Post Deployment Script with Create Assembly for XMLSerializers

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclr, sql-server-data-tools

How can i have 'Create Assembly' reference the build output path.

I have an SQL CLR that references a web service.

I have an entry in the PostDeployment script

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY TestWebServiceClientXML from N'\\TestServer2012\clrdeploy\Test\TestWebServiceClient.XmlSerializers.dll' WITH permission_set = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```

Currently this works fine. I build the TestWebServiceClient separately manually, that builds the dll and XMLSerializer dll to a share that SQL can see. When i then publish the database project with the CLR in that references this, the PostDeployment scripts uses the XMLSerializers dll I've just built from the share.

How can I get this scenario to work with a build server? All the build outputs, including the XMLSerializers dll will go to a single build output path on the build server and when the post deployment script runs it will create an assembly from an old version on the share '\TestServer2012\clrdeploy\Test\' as this is hard coded, not the version just built.

Eventually I want this to run within Release Management. Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1):

Using [SQLCMD variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), have the build server pass the build folder's path to [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) as a SQLCMD variable. Then modify your post deployment script to look something like this:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY TestWebServiceClientXML from N'$(BuildFolder)\clrdeploy\Test\TestWebServiceClient.XmlSerializers.dll' WITH permission_set = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```